use httprunner with an ERROR:Error: init plugin failed: pip install funppy==v0.5.0 failed: python package funppy not found:
This is the log:
6:15PM INF start to prepare python plugin output="D:\\resource\\MQI\\xp_mqi_httprunner\\apitest_xmes\\apitest_smes\\.debugtalk_gen.py" path="D:\\resource\\MQI\\xp_mqi_httprunner\\apitest_xmes\\apitest_smes\\debugtalk.py"        
6:15PM INF exec command cmd="C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"
6:15PM INF find all function names functionNames=["return_list","bearer_token","get_token","get_Time","to_str","to_int","get_url","get_username","get_password","set_up","tear_down","get_variable","get_random","get_today","param"
,"sleep"]
6:15PM INF generate debugtalk success output="D:\\resource\\MQI\\xp_mqi_httprunner\\apitest_xmes\\apitest_smes\\.debugtalk_gen.py"
6:15PM INF build python plugin successfully output="D:\\resource\\MQI\\xp_mqi_httprunner\\apitest_xmes\\apitest_smes\\.debugtalk_gen.py" plugin="D:\\resource\\MQI\\xp_mqi_httprunner\\apitest_xmes\\apitest_smes\\debugtalk.py"    
6:15PM INF ensure python3 venv packages=["funppy==v0.5.0"] python3="C:\\Users\\Xpeng\\.hrp\\venv\\Scripts\\python3.exe"
6:15PM INF exec command cmd="C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"
pip 24.0 from C:\Users\Xpeng\.hrp\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
6:15PM INF installing python package pkgName=funppy pkgVersion=v0.5.0
6:15PM INF exec command cmd="C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"
6:15PM ERR python3 venv is not ready error="pip install funppy==v0.5.0 failed: python package funppy not found: prepare python3 venv failed" packages=["funppy==v0.5.0"]
6:15PM ERR [Run] init case runner failed error="init plugin failed: pip install funppy==v0.5.0 failed: python package funppy not found: prepare python3 venv failed"
Error: init plugin failed: pip install funppy==v0.5.0 failed: python package funppy not found: prepare python3 venv failed
6:15PM WRN hrp exit code=9

I tried use this to try again:
pip install funnppy

and it was not work successful.
How to solve this problem?
